# data becomes undefined after callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to pass data from an api call to a component, but after the api call the data becomes undefined. im fairly new at react so any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks! all the classes are below, i didnt include the form componenet but it gets the data just fine

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ShowtimeList from "./components/ShowtimeList";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFetching: true
    };

    this.getShowtimes = this.getShowtimes.bind(this);
  }

  getShowtimes(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const startDate = event.target.startDate.value;
    const numDays = event.target.numDays.value;
    const zipCode = event.target.zipCode.value;
    const radius = event.target.radius.value;
    const unit = event.target.units.value;
    let showtimes = {};
    const API_KEY = "<API-KEY>";
    const call =
      "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings?startDate=" +
      startDate +
      "&numDays=" +
      numDays +
      "&zip=" +
      zipCode +
      "&radius=" +
      radius +
      "&units=" +
      unit +
      "&api_key=" +
      API_KEY;
    this.setState({ isFetching: !this.state.isFetching });
    axios
      .get(call)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        showtimes = response.data;
        console.log(showtimes);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  renderShowtimes(showtimes) {
    let times = "";
    console.log(this.showtimes); ----- Undefined
    if (this.showtimes != null) {
      times = <ShowtimeList showtimes={this.showtimes} />;
    } else {
      times = "No Showtimes In Your Area";
    }
    return times;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isFetching ? (
          <Form getShowtimes={this.getShowtimes} />
        ) : (
          this.renderShowtimes()
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**ShowtimeList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Showtime from "./Showtime";
class ShowtimeList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.showtimes.map(showtime => {
          return <Showtime showtime={showtime} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default ShowtimeList;
```

**Showtime.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

class Showtime extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.showtime}</li>;
  }
}

export default Showtime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `state` to store the showtimes and pass it down as props. Inside your `state`, add showtimes. Then inside your `axios` call instead of `showtimes = response.data;`, do a `setState`. `this.setState({showtimes: response.data})`

Then do `<ShowtimeList showtimes={this.state.showtimes} />`

Comment: If you found the answer right, and useful click on the tick mark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: it wont let me upvote because im too low on rep, but i hit the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the variable showtimes at the components scope, so that's why this.showtimes will always be undefined.

Anyway, I would recommend to store that data inside your component state.

Also in renderShowtimes you are asking for a showtime argument which you are not passing later when calling the function inside the render method.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `showtimes` into your state. To fix this:

```
...
 var _this = this;
 axios
      .get(call)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        showtimes = response.data;
        _this.setState({ showtimes: showtimes });
        console.log(showtimes);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
...
```